# I'm trying to learn to code a bot for Discord in Java, and I'm getting the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, discord, bots, discord-jda

```
package fonsarelli.BorisDestroyer;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;

public class BorisDestroyer {
    public static JDA jda;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder.createDefault("Token_Goes_Here");
    }
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMQxe.png)

[Package explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTJva.png)

I'm not sure how to fix this. Everything I've found is using an outdated version of JDA. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ensure the jar containing  net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder.class is present in classpath.

Comment: I've just added a screenshot of the package explorer sorry

Comment: Try to use the [Maven Dependency](https://bintray.com/dv8fromtheworld/maven/JDA/4.2.0_206) of the JDA.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/2%29-Setup

Comment: Bit of a dumb question but are you positive you have JDA set up correctly? have you added your jda dependecies.jar and javadocs etc?